# db4o inherited object not being indexed: bug or by design?

Tags: c#, db4o

It seems that db4o will ignore config parameters where you are trying to index a field on an object that is inherited from another object.  For example, if I have the following:

```
public class foo
{
    private int theId;
    public int TheId {get{return theId;}set{theId=value;}}
}

public class bar:foo
{
    private string name;
    public string Name{get{return name;}set{name=value;}}
}
```

My configuration can resemble this:

```
IEmbeddedConfiguration config = Db4oEmbedded.NewConfiguration();
config.Common.ObjectClass(typeof(foo)).ObjectField("theId").Indexed(true);
```

and this will work.  However, if I try to do this:

```
IEmbeddedConfiguration config = Db4oEmbedded.NewConfiguration();
config.Common.ObjectClass(typeof(bar)).ObjectField("theId").Indexed(true);
```

the configuration is ignored; `bar`.`TheId` is not indexed.

I can see why this might be as designed, but I can find no documentation referencing this behavior, or noting this as a possible "gotcha".  So is it a bug, or by design?  It seems to me there might be many times when you would want to index the field only on a specific subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is by design. You can only index field on the classes it is declared on. This then also applies to all sub classes.

Afaik, indexing a inherited field only on a subclass is not possible right now.

Added a documentation task for [this](http://tracker.db4o.com/browse/DOC-708).